# How to use vim LatexSuite with a Makefile?

Tags: latex-suite

I would like to type `:make` in Vim to compile my LaTeX document. I wrote down compilation rules in a `Makefile`, but as soon as I enable the LatexSuite Vim extension, the `Makefile` is no longer used. Instead, Vim runs `latex -interaction=nonstopmode` (note the absence of a filename) and hangs in that command. I did not change the `g:Tex_UseMakefile` option from its default 1 to 0 and according to the documentation, that should cause my `Makefile` to be used, but it's not.

What configuration is needed to tell LatexSuite to just use my `Makefile`?

LatexSuite was obtained via OpenSuSE repositories: vim-plugin-latex-20120125-21.1.1.noarch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override this via following setting in your vimrc.

```
autocmd FileType tex let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'make'
```

Alternatively, set makeprg in `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`

```
set makeprg='make'
```

Helpful in-source documentation of file `<latex-suite-root-folder>/compiler/tex.vim`

Section `" Customization of 'makeprg': {{{`

> This (g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi) is a string which should be directly be able to be cast into
>   " &makeprg.

Comment: The proposed solutions work for me. Do you also know why `g:Tex_UseMakefile` is ignored entirely? It seems that there are two files competing to set `makeprg`: `ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim` and `compiler/tex.vim`. Why are there two?

Comment: I am not too familiar with the details. I was looking for an answer of your question by myself since ```g:Tex_UseMakefile``` does not work for some reason. I couldn't figure out what it is. Since the development of latex-suite is more or less stalled (no commits since 1 1/2 year according to sf.net), I fear that this will not get fixed.